TikZ line with width \textwidth gives overfull \hbox – why?
The below code gives Overfull \hbox (2.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--7. I know that a warning is not the end of the world, but still. I know that I could \rlap it, but this feels like sweeping the problem under the carpet.
Notice that I do have \noindent, so this question does not provide a solution.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\noindent\tikz\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (0:\textwidth);

\lipsum
\end{document}



You can avoid the overfull box with (0:\textwidth-\pgflinewidth)
